# Is there a generic way to dismiss all modals and cookie warnings using Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

When taking a screenshot using puppeteer I would like to dismiss all cookie warnings and modals before taking the screenshot. Is there a generic way to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no generic way.

Comment: maybe if you want to open some websites, then you can write all of the modal and cookie warnings selector in puppeteer, and let puppeteer close them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select them and delete/hide one by one I'm afraid